# Can not deploy Rails to production. DEPLOY FAILED, Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.5)

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Hi I'm a little stuck with with this. Never had this issue in the past. I get this error below in capistrano log details. I tried to update mimemagic and followed this here https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mimemagicrb/mimemagic

**The error**

Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.5), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of mimemagic (0.3.5) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a version other than mimemagic (0.3.5) that hasn't been removed in order to install.

I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

So this is due to mimemagic being yanked due to copyright issues. Anyways, I'm on a mac and I'm using rails 6, I'm not sure what you'd do if you're using older versions of rails. My issue got solved by doing the following:

First please make sure you have work committed to git prior to doing anything.

In gem file

```
gem 'mimemagic', '>= 0.3.8'
```

Then in your terminal run

```
brew install shared-mime-info
```

or you may have to run

```
brew upgrade shared-mime-info
```

Finally run

```
bundle update marcel mimemagic
```

So that solved the issues for me. Here is a good reference.

https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic/issues/98

Also you may want to follow up on any copyright infringements.